# Vertical coloured title with mdframed

Tags: spacing, color, mdframed, frame-title

I'm trying without sucess to make an environment like this:

[image]

What I have know is this:

[image]

The perfect answer to this question would be a way to have the title in colors and text  out of the mdframed environment. The reason of this is because if you have to many text (or larges equations), mdframed goes crazy with "overfull \vbox". Part of my code is this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}


\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\newcounter{solution}[section]
\renewcommand{\thesolution}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{solution}}

\newenvironment{solution}[1][]{%
    \refstepcounter{solution}

    % Always:
    \mdfsetup{leftmargin = 0.25cm, rightmargin = 0cm,
        innertopmargin = 0.25cm, linecolor = gray!50,
        linewidth = 2pt, topline = true, 
        frametitleaboveskip = \dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax}

    % 'if' condition (without title)
    \ifstrempty{#1}%
        {\mdfsetup{frametitle = {%
            \tikz[baseline = (current bounding box.east), 
            outer sep = 0pt]
            \node[anchor = east, rectangle, fill = gray!50]
            {\strut Soluci\'on};}}
        }
    % 'else' condition (with title)
        {\mdfsetup{frametitle = {%
            \tikz[baseline = (current bounding box.east), 
            outer sep = 0pt]
            \node[anchor = east, rectangle, fill= gray!50]
            {\strut Soluci\'on: #1};}}
        }
    
        
    \begin{mdframed}[]\relax}{%
    \end{mdframed}}
```

By the way, what I mean with "goes crazy" is this:

[image]

Thanks for read!

Comment: try with tcolorbox, it has much more options that mdframed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ulrike suggested, it can be easily done with `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mwe}%for testing purpose only
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins, breakable}
\newtcolorbox{solution}[2][]{%
enhanced,breakable,
attach boxed title to top left,
left = 0.25cm, right = 0cm,
%frame hidden,
title={\strut Soluci\'on: #2},
colbacktitle=gray!50,
coltitle=black,fonttitle=\bfseries,
attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2, xshift=4mm},
boxed title style={sharp corners,colframe=gray!50, boxsep=0pt},
top=\tcboxedtitleheight/2+2mm,
opacityframe=0, opacityback=0,
borderline horizontal={0.5mm}{0pt}{gray!50},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{solution}{Title of the solution}
Something something 
\end{solution}
\begin{solution}{Another solution}
It is also breakable

For testing purpose only: \blindtext[4]
\end{solution}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

*Edit:*
Using a default title if the title is empty:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mwe}%for testing purpose only
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins, breakable}
\newtcolorbox{solution}[2][]{%
enhanced,breakable,
attach boxed title to top left,
left = 0.25cm, right = 0cm,
%frame hidden,
title={\strut Soluci\'on: \ifstrempty{#2}{Default title}{#2}},
colbacktitle=gray!50,
coltitle=black,fonttitle=\bfseries,
attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2, xshift=4mm},
boxed title style={sharp corners,colframe=gray!50, boxsep=0pt},
top=\tcboxedtitleheight/2+2mm,
opacityframe=0, opacityback=0,
borderline horizontal={0.5mm}{0pt}{gray!50},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{solution}{Title of the solution}
Something something 
\end{solution}
\begin{solution}{}
Something something 
\end{solution}
\begin{solution}{Another solution}
It is also breakable

For testing purpose only: \blindtext[4]
\end{solution}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: would be possible to have two titles? (like "if" conditions) One would be use when the solution environment doesn't have a title and the second would be the replacement of the first when the environment has a title. Do I explain myself?

Comment: @Peluche Do you like somewhat like a not mandatory title? If the title is present: "Solution: the given title", if it is not present: "Solution: the default title"?

Comment: Yes, precisely that

Comment: @Peluche Look at my edit, I hope it's what you like.

Comment: Yess, thanks you!!

Comment: @Peluche You're welcome!